# "references" statement in SQL

Tags: sql, reference

I have a table in SQL like;

```
table Court
    CourtID  numeric(4) primary key
    Name     varchar(40) not null
    Place    varchar(40) not null
    Type     varchar(3) not null
    TypeID   numeric(4) references Court(CourtID) default null
```

I could not find info about what that reference statement stands for and how does it relate TypeID with CourtID?

Comment: TypeID is not used in any other tables, so that is why I thought it was not a foreign key, it just references the very same tables primary key. But why for could that be?

Comment: foreign keys are allowed to be self-referential

Comment: Look into the manual of your DBMS for the `CREATE TABLE` statement - it's all explained there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply shorthand syntax for a FOREIGN KEY.

All sorts of Google results are found with "sql references keyword"

Or simply trying it can often help more than a Google search (the old fashioned way).

Your example shows a self-referential foreign key. It is a common pattern seen to model relationships like PARENT or SPOUSE, where all records belong in the same base table, but may reference each other.

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create table court(
  2  courtid integer primary key,
  3  typeid integer references court(courtid)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into court values(1,0);
insert into court values(1,0)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MSMITH.SYS_C0016710) violated - parent key not
found

SQL> insert into court values(1,1);

1 row created.
```

The above syntax will generate a "random" name for the constraint. A better syntax is to explicitly name the constraint. Notice what happens if I recreate it with additional FOREIGN KEY syntax.

```
SQL> create table court(
  2  courtid integer primary key,
  3  typeid integer,
  4  constraint fk_typeid foreign key (typeid) references court(courtid)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into court values(1,0);
insert into court values(1,0)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MSMITH.FK_TYPEID) violated - parent key not
found
```

The key is now named FK_TYPEID rather than SYS_C0016710